# PayPal REST API: how to encode clientId and secret with axios or curl?

Tags: javascript, curl, paypal, axios, paypal-sandbox

Here is the official Connect With PayPal docs that I have been following: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/connect-with-paypal/integrate/#6-get-access-token

I have all of the things to succeed: clientId, secretKey and authorizationCode

I have called the API via curl the following way:

```
curl -X POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
-H 'Authorization: Basic {clientId:secretKey}' \
-d 'grant_type=authorization_code&code={authorizationCode}'
```

But I get {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client Authentication failed"} all the time

And I have tried calling the API from my front end:

```
const login = async (code) => {
    const config = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Basic ${clientId}:${secretKey}`,
            'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        data: `grant_type=authorization_code&code=${authorizationCode}`
    }
    await axios(config);
}
```

But, it leads to this error:
POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token 401 (Unauthorized)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${clientId}:${secretKey}` needs to be base64 encoded

In JavaScript you can use `btoa()`, toString('base64'), or [with axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) set the `auth` key.

With curl you can use the `-u` command line parameter.

---

For general rest API usage, when passing a basic auth that way to the oauth2/token endpoint, your query string should be `grant_type=client_credentials`, as [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/get-an-access-token-curl/).  This will return the access_token that you can use in all other API calls.

The 'Connect with PayPal' documentation you linked to is for that specific integration, which you need an authorization code, but no other API uses that.